# Is there any risk to making my AWS account totally public with the ViewOnlyAccess policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm creating some software and for the demonstration version I am planning to publicly hand out the programmatic access keys to an AWS user that has the ViewOnlyAccess policy. Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_job-functions.html#jf_view-only-user

Thus this demonstration user would have full access to see all the AWS resources in my account.

Is there any risk to this? My understanding is this policy reveals only details about the AWS infrastructure, but no actual information.

Nevertheless I thought I'd ask as it seems a big step to go completely public without asking.

Comment: Do you have any sensitive data in the account? Is it linked to any account via AWS Ogranixations?

Comment: The account contains no sensitive data but is linked to AWS Organisations.

Comment: [AWS IAM "ReadOnlyAccess" Managed Policy Is Too Permissive (For Us) - Alestic.com](https://alestic.com/2015/10/aws-iam-readonly-too-permissive/)

Comment: [Read-only IAM Permissions to all users - what are the security risks? : aws](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/8njyju/readonly_iam_permissions_to_all_users_what_are/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm using the ViewOnlyAccess - see link above.

Comment: Ah! Yes, `ViewOnlyAccess` seems a lot safer than `ReadOnlyAccess`. It would also have the benefit of avoiding a lot of error messages in the AWS management console due to listings being disabled. It gives no IAM permissions, so avenues for misadventure are relatively small.